# Why my win7 home premium system doesnot walk into sleep mode after an enough inactive time?

Tags: windows-7, sleep

I am using win7 home premium 64-bit. When I manually click the sleep button, my computer can fall into sleep mode -- that is to say, both the monitor and computer case are shut down. **But when I leave the computer enough inactive time, only the monitor is shut down.**

I am sure all the settings is OK, please see the pictures below:

[image]

Comment: are you currently set to the power plan in which these settings are applied to?

Comment: @Mike Koch I am not sure, how to check this?

Comment: Start --> Control Panel --> Power Options. It should say in the "Select a power plan" screen (which is the default screen when you click "Power Options"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like on the left, you have `600分` which, I believe, translates to 600 minutes. Try maybe lowering that amount to the one you want.

Comment: that's dormant mode. Anyway, I change it to 1, still doesnot work.